# How to find numbers like 174

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integers, integer-programming

We know Ramanujan number:
$1729 = 1^3+12^3 = 9^3+10^3$

The smallest number expressible as the sum of cubes of two positive integers in two different ways.

We also know how to find other Ramanujan numbers:

$n^3 +(12n)^3 = (9n)^3 + (10n)^3$

In the same way, I want to find $174$
$$\begin{align*} 174
&=1^2+2^2+5^2+12^2\\
&=1^2+3^2+8^2+10^2\\
&=1^2+4^2+6^2+11^2\\
&=2^2+5^2+8^2+9^2\\
&=3^2+4^2+7^2+10^2\\
&=5^2+6^2+7^2+8^2\\
\end{align*}$$

Thus $174$ is the smallest number which can be expressed as the sum of squares of $4$-**different integers** in $6$ different ways.

How can I find such numbers and don't want to miss any number?

Any algorithm/logical idea is welcome.

Comment: We [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131416/number-of-ways-of-representing-a-number-as-the-sum-of-four-squares), how many such representations of $n$ by $4$ squares exists. The algorithm to find them is straightforward. Just start with $x=1$ in $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=n$ and so on, as you did in the example.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1358472_representation_of_a_number_the_squares_in_different_ways

Comment: If you want to brute force this, note that a number is congruent to the number of odd squares involved modulo $4$.

Comment: It's also congruent to the number of squares not a multiple of $3$ modulo $3$

Comment: 1729 is the smallest number expressible in two ways as the sum of two _positive_ cubes.  $91 = 3^3+4^3 = 6^3 + (-5)^3$.

Comment: Another help is if you say $y\approx 4\cdot x^2$ either all values are $x$ or there's at least one greater than $x$ in base value.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A025381

Comment: this link can get the sum of 4 squares for integers. It also give the algorithm. I don't know if it can handle big numbers. If you do a search on sum of 4 squares on this site (math.SE), you will find many links. https://www.mathcelebrity.com/foursquare.php

Comment: We also have that a square multiple of any that work, have at least the same number.

Comment: @DarshanPatil, here's a link that may be useful for you. It describes computational methods of getting the sum of 4 squares. Title: How fast can we find all Four-Square combinations that sum to N? Link: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-fast-can-we-find-all-four-square-combinations-that-sum-to-n?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot you could throw at it actually. Some of these include :

$$y=mx+b\land p\mid m, p\in \mathbb{P} \implies y^p\equiv b^p\pmod {pm}$$
$$y=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\implies a\leq b\leq c\leq d$$

The fact that distinct $(a,b,c,d)$ for each sum is only possible above $576=24^2$ because there will be $24$ squares involved. Any with duplicates are based on numbers representable as a sum of $3$ or fewer squares.

If $(a,b,c,d)$ have a pair that form two lower legs of a Pythagorean triple then the current number plus a square will always have at least $1$ representation as $4$ squares

If $(a,b,c,d)$ works then $x^2(a,b,c,d)$ is a representation for a multiplier that's square. Therefore, we can reduce the search to square-free numbers  somewhat, because if the radical of $\frac{n}{p}$  works, then it's sufficient to show $np$ has **at least** as many as required , we just need to rule out it having too many.

Another avenue is looking at the product of two numbers that are a sum of two squares. It always has a representation with four squares.